# How to make Android Studio and Eclipse coexist (gradle dependencies)

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, gradle, eclipse-wtp

I need to use **Eclipse** and **Android Studio** on the same computer, simultaneously, for different projects.

The Eclipse project is Enterprise Java deploying on Payara (Glassfish) via the WTP toolkit and Deployment Assembly. When setting up the project I build with `gradle build` and `gradle eclipse`, which pulls all the required dependencies and configures the Deployment Assembly in Eclipse. However, I believe that any incremental code changes thereafter are compiled by Eclipse without using gradle (e.g., when I save a file).

Android Studio always compiles with gradle.

The issue that I have is that every couple of weeks, when I compile my Android Studio project, gradle decides to delete all my Eclipse project dependencies. My guess is that it thinks that they are not in use any more, since Eclipse compiles outside gradle. This results in my Eclipse workspace pointing to libs that are no longer there.

If I manually run `gradle build` in my Eclipse project dir, my dependencies are restored and Eclipse no longer complains. But something seems to be cached wrong somewhere so after this my web app will no longer deploy on the server. At that point my workspace is effectively corrupted and to this day I haven't found any workaround, other than to delete it and start all over again. Which is *A LOT* of work to reconfigure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you use `gradle eclipse` instead of importing it as Gradle project?

Comment: I've tried importing it as a Gradle project but it doesn't make a difference with respect to incremental file changes thereafter. Eclipse seems to compile them outside Gradle.

Comment: Did you delete the files created by `gradle eclipse` (`.classpath`, `.project`, etc.) before importing the project? Eclipse uses its own incremental compiler, but you talked about dependencies.

Comment: No, I didn't delete any files. I'm assuming you are thinking that I should be using the 'buildship" plugin for Eclipse? If this was working correctly, how would it help? Would saving a file in Eclipse use Gradle instead of the built-in compiler? Or would I have to invoke the build task manually (e.g., similar to typing `gradle build` in the command line?

Comment: `gradle eclipse` creates a `.classpath` file that lists all dependencies, while importing the project as a Gradle project creates a `.classpath` file (if it not yet exists!) that only points to `build.gradle` without listing the dependencies. So, if you did `gradle eclipse` which you shouldn't, delete the `.classpath` and `.project` files and then import it as Gradle project. Otherwise, you have to run `gradle eclipse` each time after updating the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: ok, I did `Gradle > Add Gradle Nature`, which converted the existing project into a Gradle project. Now `.classpath` (and the Deploymet Assembly) no longer lists all the dependencies. I can now also make changes to `build.gradle` and then select `Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project` to synchronize everything. So, `gradle eclipse` is no longer needed. The app compiles and deploys correctly as expected. Now back to the actual problem: I change a file and save it. The Eclipse compiler kicks in. I don't see any Gradle tasks running.

Comment: So the only time gradle will be running from now on, is whenever I make changes in my code in Android Studio. Code changes made in Eclipse will not trigger gradle. My guess is then that after a month or so, when gradle is invoked from Android Studio, it will see that my Eclipse project dependencies have not been used for a while and will remove them from the local repository. Then next time I try to build something in Eclipse, the project will fail. This is the problem I'm having right now. By what mechanism do you envisage this current setup helping with this problem? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what Android Studio does. Eclipse relies on the dependencies in the local Gradle repository/cache not being deleted.